# phpMyAdmin not starting in EasyPHP

Tags: phpmyadmin, easyphp

Just installed Easy PHP16.1 under Windows 10, recently updated.

Started MySQL but could not find phpMyAdmin, no error code.

Apparently many services linked to EasyPHP running.
Any solution (tip or old version)?

Answer (score 0):

Start HTTP Server and DB Server and then in the modules section you will see **Open** on the right side of **MySQL Administration : PhpMyAdmin**

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use an old version, use EasyPhp 14.1, works fine for me if it doesn't work your actual version.